# Align child elements in parent flex containers

Tags: css, alignment, less, flexbox, parent-child

I need help horizontally aligning child elements in parent flex boxes.

The layout below shows a flex container (".parent") showing 4 parent containers (".child"):

[Please take a look at this flexbox graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zioJ2.gif)
(I can't show my actual project so I mocked it up in Illustrator.)

- The green box (top) represents a variable text headline (max 3 lines).
- The blue box (second one down) represents an image with fixed height and width
  (*I want these images to be aligned on top*).
- The yellow box represents a paragraph of varying copy.
- The purple box on the bottom is another fixed-height flex box.

I have the following code (in LESS):

```
.parent {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-flow: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;

    .child {
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex:1;
        flex:1;
        -webkit-flex-flow: column;
        -ms-flex-flow: column;
        flex-flow: column;
        -webkit-align-content: space-around;
        align-content: space-around;

        .green {
            -webkit-align-items: baseline;
            -ms-flex-align: baseline;
            align-items: baseline;
            }

        .blue {
            -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
            -ms-flex-align: start;
            align-items: flex-start;
        }

        .purple {
            -webkit-flex: 1;
            -ms-flex:1;
            flex:1;
            display: -webkit-flex;
            display: -ms-flexbox;
            display: flex;
            -webkit-flex-flow: row;
            -ms-flex-flow: row;
            flex-flow: row;
            -webkit-align-items: flex-end;
            -ms-flex-align: end;
            align-items: flex-end;
            -webkit-order: 3;
            -ms-flex-order: 3;
            order: 3;
        }

        .yellow {
            -webkit-order: 2;
            -ms-flex-order: 2;
            order: 2;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT - and here's the HTML code:

```
<section class="parent">

        <article class="child">
            <a href="#">
                <h3 class="green">Title of article</h3>
                <div class="blue"><img class="img-responsive" src="/stuff/headerImage.png" /></div>
            </a>
            <section class="purple">
                <div class="authorImage"><img src="/writers/JohnDoe.jpg") /></div>
                <h4 class="authorTitle">by John Doe</h4>
            </section>
            <p class="yellow">Paragraph introducing article summary.</p>
        </article>

        <article class="child">
            <a href="#">
                <h3 class="green">Title of article</h3>
                <div class="blue"><img class="img-responsive" src="/stuff/headerImage.png" /></div>
            </a>
            <section class="purple">
                <div class="authorImage"><img src="/writers/JohnDoe.jpg") /></div>
                <h4 class="authorTitle">by John Doe</h4>
            </section>
            <p class="yellow">Paragraph introducing article summary.</p>
        </article>

        <article class="child">
            <a href="#">
                <h3 class="green">Title of article</h3>
                <div class="blue"><img class="img-responsive" src="/stuff/headerImage.png" /></div>
            </a>
            <section class="purple">
                <div class="authorImage"><img src="/writers/JohnDoe.jpg") /></div>
                <h4 class="authorTitle">by John Doe</h4>
            </section>
            <p class="yellow">Paragraph introducing article summary.</p>
        </article>

        <article class="child">
            <a href="#">
                <h3 class="green">Title of article</h3>
                <div class="blue"><img class="img-responsive" src="/stuff/headerImage.png" /></div>
            </a>
            <section class="purple">
                <div class="authorImage"><img src="/writers/JohnDoe.jpg") /></div>
                <h4 class="authorTitle">by John Doe</h4>
            </section>
            <p class="yellow">Paragraph introducing article summary.</p>
        </article>

</section>
```

Comment: Can you share the html structure or a codepen with the code you have tried?

Comment: That probably would have been helpful -oops! I've edited the question to include my HTML.